# fastlane - error at google cloud build: "OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345"

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, fastlane, google-container-registry, google-cloud-build

I'm using `fastlane` container that stores at google container registry to upload APK to google play store using `Google Cloud Build`.

APK has been succesfully created.However, when processing last step (**fastlane**), it face errors:

```
Step #2: 487ea6dabc0c: Pull complete
Step #2: a7ae4fee33c9: Pull complete
Step #2: Digest: sha256:2e31d5ae64984a598856f1138c6be0577c83c247226c473bb5ad302f86267545
Step #2: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/myapp789-app/fastlane:latest
Step #2: gcr.io/myapp789-app/fastlane:latest
Step #2: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"supply\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
Step #2: time="2019-08-29T23:22:55Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: context canceled"
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/myapp789-app/fastlane" failed: exit status 127
```

Note:

1) Docker Source file was taken from **https://hub.docker.com/r/fastlanetools/fastlane** and then I build my own image.

2) Docker Image Build on **Google Cloud VM** using `Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)`

### Docker Source File for fastlane:

```
# Final image #
###############
FROM circleci/ruby:latest
MAINTAINER milch

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/itms/bin

# Java versions to be installed
ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u131
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u131-b11-1~bpo8+1
ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION 20161107~bpo8+1

# Needed for fastlane to work
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

# Required for iTMSTransporter to find Java
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre

USER root

# iTMSTransporter needs java installed
# We also have to install make to install xar
# And finally shellcheck
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-
backports.list \
        && apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update \
        && apt-get install --yes \
                make \
                shellcheck \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER circleci

COPY --from=xar_builder /tmp/xar /tmp/xar

RUN cd /tmp/xar \
        && sudo make install \
        && sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
```

**CloudBuild.yaml:**

```
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/fastlane'
  args: ['supply', '--package_name','${_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME}', '--track', '${_ANDROID_RELEASE_CHANNEL}', '--json_key_data', '${_GOOGLE_PLAY_UPLOAD_KEY_JSON}', '--apk', '/workspace/${_REPO_NAME}/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab']
timeout: 1200s
```

Any Idea to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide any of your own source code (Dockerfiles or other artifacts) to help reproduce the issue?  It seems like you got a pretty clear error message, is a (Linux) `supply` binary somewhere in the standard `$PATH`?

Comment: @DavidMaze please see my updated question, thank you

Comment: @DavidMaze i'm using google VM (debian stretch) to create docker image then upload it to Google Container Registry

Comment: `is a (Linux) supply binary somewhere in the standard $PATH?` - sorry what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by building docker image using docker source from **[Google Cloud Official](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/fastlane)** other than fastlane on **hub.docker.com** (where's it never update since 5 month ago)

Comment: Can you provide me some idea how to create iOS android CICD in Cloud build. I am stuck, there is no documentation on gcp regarding this